# google conversion AJAX form with GTM

Tags: ajax, google-ads-api, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to track conversions on an AJAX Form, I'm using google tag manger to control any conversion and other google tags,

at the end of the AJAX form proccess i'm not sending the client to a "Thank you" page, in fact the user is greeted with a 'thank you' message.

how can I implement a conversion code after the ajax form as completed (using GTM - google tag manager) , i have tried a rule that GTM will trigger upon url with css selecteor #thanks, and on the ajax function i have done on success:

```
window.location.href = window.location.href + "#thanks";
```

but that didn't work.

Comment: Do you use a javascript framework like jQuery for your Ajax requests ? Many frameworks allow to hook into the ajax events via a global ajax event handler.

Comment: yes sure, im using jQuery for my AJAX requset.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery (and Prototype and possibly many other frameworks) have the concept of global Ajax event handlers that hook into Ajax events without the need to change the function that does the request.

E.g. if you want to check if your form has been sent you'd use the ajax success handler.  That tells you if the request has been successful, i.e. if the server returns a 200 http status. It does not tell you if your server has actually sent the data, that's something you would need to include in the server response.

You can use a function like  this as a custom HTML tag:

```
<script>
(function() {
 try {
     $( document ).ajaxSuccess(function( event, xhr, settings ) {
     if ( xhr.responseText.indexOf("thank") > -1 ) {
         dataLayer.push({'event':'formSucess'});
     }
   });
} catch(e){
// silently fail if anything goes wrong
}
})(); 
</script>
```

(I like to wrap my javascript tags in self executing functions and use try/catch blocks, both as not to interfere with other scripts already on the page. But that's not essential to ajax event handling and you do not need to do this).

The ajax success handler takes three parameters (you do not need to provide values for the parameters, jQuery fills the values in itself): the ajax event (in that case always "success"), the xhr request and the configuration settings for the request (i.e. settings.url would be the url you send the data to).

If we assume that your server outputs the text string "thank you for your email" after data has been successfully submitted you could , as in the example above, inspect the responseText property of the xhr object to see if it contains a "thanks". Then push a custom event to the dataLayer and fire any tag based on that event.